# Elements with rounded corners - how to detect specific elements to give them a special style?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have kind of a strange layout - the boxes should have rounded corners as if they were one big element (see image with 4 examples). Problem is the boxes are made dynamically so the rows and columns can vary. And so the fun starts. I started with giving the first and the last box a rounded corner, after this counting (nth) - but I can't wrap my head around how to do this with different rows. Tried everything like "tnh-last-child(3)" (does not work if last "row" has only 2 boxes) or "nth-child(3n+1)" but then there is a problem when i have more than 2 "rows" (I mean there are no "rows" [would be great] - only columns). Any idea?

```
// First and last
&:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}
&:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}       
&:nth-of-type(3) {
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/eYEyRQp

```css
section {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: left;
     width: 400px;
}
 section div {
     width: 30%;
     margin: 5px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: grey;
}
 section div:first-of-type {
     border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}
 section div:last-of-type {
     border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}
 section div:nth-of-type(3) {
     border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}
 .red {
     background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Red box should always have a rounded corner in the bottom left.</h1>

<h2>Example A</h2>
<section class="a">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>

<h2>Example B</h2>
<section class="b">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div></div>
</section>

<h2>Example C</h2>
<section class="b">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</section>

<h2>Example D</h2>
<section class="b">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `nth-child` selectors. This will match with only one item.

```
&:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(3),
&:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-last-child(2),
&:nth-child(3n + 1):last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  width: 400px;
}

section div {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

section div:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}

section div:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}

section div:nth-child(3) {
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

section div:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(3),
section div:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(2),
section div:nth-child(3n+1):last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Red box should always have a rounded corner in the bottom left.</h1>

<h2>Example A</h2>
<section class="a">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>

<h2>Example B</h2>
<section class="b">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div></div>
</section>

<h2>Example C</h2>
<section class="b">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</section>

<h2>Example D</h2>
<section class="b">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```